# convert mysql query that finds the second lowest value to an sqlite query

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

i was given a query statement that finds the second lowest value comparing multiple columns and returning the result into another column called '2nd_lowest'. the query works well with MYSQL. i want to have the same result in an sqlite database but sqlite does not support the query. how can i convert the mysql query to an sqlite query..the query is as follows:

```
with num(x) as(
  values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
),
new as(
 select name, case x when 1 then score1  when 2 then score2  when 3 then score3
                     when 4 then score4  else score5 end val
   from test, num
  where val!=min(score1,score2,score3,score4,score5)
)
update test set "2nd_lowest"=
   (select min(val) from new where new.name=test.name)
```

i have this sqlite query but i get an exception error

```
update test set 2nd_lowest=(select min(val) from "
             + "( select case x when 1 then score1 when 2 then score2 when 3 then score3 when 4 then score4 else score5 end val from test T, "
             + "(select 1 as x union all values (2),(3),(4),(5))X where val!=min(score1,score2,score3,score4,score5)" +
               " and T.name=test.name ))
```

and the exception error is -

```
java.sql.SQLException:near"values":syntax error
```

when i change the 'values clause' to select clause, like the example below:

```
update test set 2nd_lowest=(select min(val) from "
                 + "( select case x when 1 then score1 when 2 then score2 when 3 then score3 when 4 then score4 else score5 end val from test T, "
                 + "(select 1 as x union all select (2),(3),(4),(5))X where val!=min(score1,score2,score3,score4,score5)" +
                   " and T.name=test.name ))<br/>
```

i get this exception:

```
Java.sql.SQLException: SELECTs to the left and right of UNION ALL do not have the same number of result columns <br/>
```

please all help will be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Which part does it not support, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: it does not support the 'with' clause starting the query @Fran.

Comment: SQLite has supported WITH for over three years. Your software is out of date.

Comment: i downloaded navicat premium for sqlite just jesterday... and i had the same exception @CL. what sqlite software will you advice i use.

Comment: And what is the output of `SELECT sqlite_version();`?

Comment: 3.13.0 @CL. thats the version number i see when i query within the sqlite Manager. but when i do the same query in netbeans, it gives me 3.6.14.2.

Comment: And what is the error message you get for the original query?

Comment: java.sql.SQLException:near"with":syntax error. thats the error message when i use the original query @CL.

Comment: Your JDBC driver is out of date.

Comment: oohk. sqlitejdbc-v056  is the sqlite driver am using currently.. which site can i get a better one

Comment: the change of jdbc driver worked. thanks @CL